# kafka-python KafkaConsumer: read latest message non-blocking

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

How can I grab the latest produced message from a Kafka Producer without looping? It has to be quick, so I cannot afford to wait for a new message to come in and instead wish to read the most recent message. What I wish to do is equivalent to the following code, except I would rather not read every message using `list(consumer)`.

```py
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'my-topic',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
    auto_offset_reset='earliest'
)
consumer.poll()

# read all messages and keep latest
latest_message = list(consumer)[-1]
print(latest_message)

consumer.close()
```

I suspect it has something to do with finding the latest offset and setting to the previous offset, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Kafka might not be the right tool if you always only want the very last message in the topic, but listing the offsets would be done with AdminClient, rather than the KafkaConsumer class.

Comment: Got it. I guess that would be with `list_consumer_group_offsets`? Kafka is a must because I have to rely on a service that publishes its data to Kafka. Perhaps I could listen to the event stream in a separate thread as long as I don't block the main thread. The docs say KafkaClient is not thread-safe though.

Comment: Assuming you have a consumer group, yes. Finding the offsets for a topic doesn't require one, however. Regarding non-blocking, `aiokafka` library would be useful for that

Comment: Keep in mind that by the time you read that latest message, a producer could have already pushed a bunch of new messages. So, if you really want just a single entry, use a database query for that

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. With your help I was able to solve my problem using a non-blocking client. I'm not sure I should post it as a solution though since it doesn't address the question the way I stated it.